# VSCode, Python, Run in new interactive window

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, window, interactive

In VSCode, I use shift+enter to run python code in an interactive window. However, if I run more code with shift+enter, it will run in an additional cell in the interactive window.

I would like the interactive window to restart each time I press shift+enter, so the interactive window only shows the code that is currently run. Is there any way I can accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: If I am guessing right, you just annoyed with the outputs and want to clear the screen before every time run the cell. You can set the shortcut to achieve this. Open the Keyboard Shortcuts, search 'Python: Delete All Python Interactive Cells' and add a shortcut for it, such as 'Ctrl+Alt+L'.

Comment: Thanks that definitely helps!
Ideally I would like to have one shortcut that deletes all python interactive cells and also runs the current script in the interactive window. Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: It's unable to do it for now. As the shortcut of 'shift+enter': to run the code in the interactive was the built-in shortcut and unable to be configured. If you bind 'Python: Delete All Python Interactive Cells' with shortcut 'shift+enter', it still doesn't work because 'run the code' has a higher priority than 'Python: Delete All Python Interactive Cells'.